# UIAlertView "non-blocking" show message does retain the view?

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have a simple question for you... I was reading Beginning IOS 4 Development book and there is the following code example:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@”Hello”
                                    message:@”This is an alert view”
                                   delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@”OK”
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Then it points out that the show message shows the alert view but the code does not stop it's execution until the user dismisses the dialog, it goes on and executes the following code... since next to the show message there is a release message, does the show method retain the view until it is dismissed? Otherwise I should not release it after the show message has been sent.. I'm sorry but I did not find this information on the reference pages, so I hope this is not a (too much) stupid question.

OT: how do I activate colors on code snippets?

Comment: I believe that `[alert show]` increases the retain count because it is added as a subview, but that really shouldn't be your concern.  You alloc'd the item, so you should release it when done, which you are in this case following the show statement

Comment: I would just go with this:`UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@”Hello”
                                    message:@”This is an alert view”
                                   delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@”OK”
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];`.  Then call show and forget about the alert as it will be autoreleased when necessary.

Comment: @cpjolicoeur Tank you.. I know I can forget about who retains it as long as I release it correctly, but it was just to understand the underlying mechanisms, since I'm new to IOS development and I like to understand the details :) BTW, I've read about the increase of the retain count when adding a view as a subview, so it could be the show method that retains the alert view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window that displays the alert view retains its reference, so you don't have to.

Comment: Ok, so it's being retained when added as a subview, as said above.. Thank you ;-)

Comment: @an0 I know it is late, but where is this documented? I am also sure about that, but I can't find a specific point in the doc where it states that.

Comment: @NicolaMiotto it's not documented. It is by convention: the API is designed in this way so you don't have to hold onto the alert view because it is usually transient.

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered this and concluded that something in the `show` method, likely a call to `addSubview:` increments the retain count on the UIAlertView preventing it from being dealloc-ed.

Comment: I think it's more likely the show method that retains the view or whatever object adds it as a subview.. I don't think the delegate needs to retain the alert view since it's the alert view that points to the delegate when events happens, while the delegate does not reference it usually... Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. I'll amend my answer